# Flask BuildError related to blueprint

Tags: python, flask

I have a views.py module under "users" package in my app. I defined a blueprint on it named "users". When I try to use `url_for('users.login')` in login.html file, it gives an error like

```
BuildError: ('users.login', {}, None)
```

Directory structure:

```
/project    
    config.py
    run.py
    /project/templates/login.html
    /project/users/views.py
```

How should I use it? Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question and include the relevant contents of views.py file (e.g., creation of the blueprint, definition of the login view, etc.).

Comment: I had a mistake because of registering blueprint before db instance was created. I changed it and problem was fixed. Thank you again.